# What is the best way to make laravel, vuejs and flutter work together?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, flutter, passport-jwt

I would like to have some advice on the best way to handle something. I have an existing application made with Laravel (without using Vuejs).
However, I will soon have to develop a mobile application (with Flutter) that will be attached to my web application. Currently, the backend is not an API and I'm not using VueJs in this project. I just want to copy all my controllers in the folder ...path/app/Http/Controllers/API and transform all the returns in JSON response to make it my API. In that case, I will have to change the code twice in case of editing which I wouldn't want to do in the long run.
Is it possible for me to have my entire backend handled by Laravel and use it with VueJs and flutter without a lot of tweaking? In that case, I will learn Vuejs. Considering the frontend and backend should be in the same repo and deployed together as a single unit. Thank you.
Also what about passport, JWT and airlock?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately this is not the right place to ask such opinionated questions. You can expect to get more downvotes and no answer.

Comment: This question has better chances at softwareengineering.stackexchange.com but it's not specific enough. *I will have to change the code twice in case of editing which I wouldn't want to do in the long run* - so you want Laravel to respond with HTML files and use them with Vue and Flutter, right? This isn't an option, it will barely work for Vue and won't work for Flutter. You need to rewrite Laravel part as API that responds with JSON any way. And then you will likely need to write the same thing twice with Vue and Flutter. Flutter supports web but cannot replace full-grown website on desktop.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for your answer. 
@EstusFlask Flutter is going to be used only the mobile application

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert your Laravel project into a backend to use as an API with a vuejs frontend for web and flutter frontend for applications.

Comment: ok thank you a lot. what about passport, JWT and airlock usage to handle that?

Comment: Just use JWT as all the frameworks that you mentioned have a JWT package.